# how to push changes to docker hub?

Tags: docker

1) I have pushed image to docker hub with

```
docker push ucanmiracle/docker-learn:node-test-image
```

2) Added changes to my project file

3) pushing docker image with

```
docker push ucanmiracle/docker-learn:node-test-image1
```

But project changes didn't applied.
How to properly push updates to docker hub?

Comment: Have you properly re-created the image? The command to push the changes is correct.

Comment: I didn't re-create it. How to do it?

Comment: The same way you created it, I imagine

Comment: Before Pushing to docker hub you need to build the updated project. Using docker build command then Push the Image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't push project files to the registry, you push an image, which needs to be built from the project files first.

1: Run `docker build -t ucanmiracle/docker-learn:node-test-image1 .` 
It will build the image from the `Dockerfile` in current directory and tag it as `ucanmiracle/docker-learn:node-test-image1`.

2: Then you run `docker push ucanmiracle/docker-learn:node-test-image1` to push the image to Docker Hub.

Check this [Link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) for more on building Docker images.

Comment: I did this, but the dockerfile that is shown online is still not up to date

Answer (score 3):

Step1:

Run below cmd from the folder where Dockerfile resides

```
docker build -t name_of_ image_with_version local_docker_dir_path

Ex:$ docker build -t base:1.0.0  .
```

Step2:

Get the docker image Tag id by running below cmd

```
$ docker images
```

if you are using docker.io ( dockerhub repo ), you need to tag it including the name docker.io in it.

```
docker tag ${image_id} docker.io/${login_name}/${image_name}

Ex: docker tag 86xc1fxyzabc9 docker.io/someone/image_name_in_docker_io
```

and then

```
docker push docker.io/${login_name}/${image_name}

Ex: docker push docker.io/someone/image_name_in_docker_io
```